# NHibernate QueryOver order by first non-null value (coalescing)

Tags: nhibernate, coalesce, queryover

What I'm trying to come up is something that's expressed like this:

```
var result = Session.QueryOver<Foo>().OrderBy(f => f.UpdatedAt ?? f.CreatedAt);
```

Sure enough, this doesn't work. Rough equivalent of this in T-SQL is

```
... order by coalesce(f.UpdatedAt, f.CreatedAt)
```

What's the kosher way to do "coalescing" in NHibernate QueryOver?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
.OrderBy(Projections.SqlFunction("coalesce",
                                 NHibernateUtil.DateTime,
                                 Projections.Property<Foo>(x => x.UpdatedAt),
                                 Projections.Property<Foo>(x => x.CreatedAt)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Diego's answer is the way I came up with, but it seemed to be too verbose to me, so I asked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38512733/nhibernate-queryover-coalesce-a-property-to-another-property), and got [an excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38667054/540312). Basically, you can register your own extensions and then just do

```
.OrderBy(f => f.UpdatedAt.IfNull(f.CreatedAt));
```

where `IfNull` is your new extension. I've even submitted [an improvement proposal](https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-3892) to NH Jira, but got no response yet.