# NHibernate QueryOver Coalesce a property to another property

Tags: c#, nhibernate, properties, fluent-nhibernate, coalesce

Consider this silly domain:

```
namespace TryHibernate.Example
{
    public class Employee
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class WorkItem
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    }

    public class Task
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public Employee Assignee { get; set; }
        public WorkItem WorkItem { get; set; }
        public string Details { get; set; }
        public DateTime? StartDateOverride { get; set; }
        public DateTime? EndDateOverride { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The idea is that each work item may be assigned to multiple employees with different details, potentially overriding start/end dates the of work item itself. If those overrides are null, they should be taken from the work item instead.

Now I'd like to perform a query with restrictions on the *effective* dates. I've tried this first:

```
IList<Task> tasks = db.QueryOver<Task>(() => taskAlias)
    .JoinAlias(() => taskAlias.WorkItem, () => wiAlias)
    .Where(() => taskAlias.StartDateOverride.Coalesce(() => wiAlias.StartDate) <= end)
    .And(() => taskAlias.EndDateOverride.Coalesce(() => wiAlias.EndDate) >= start)
    .List();
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't compile as `Coalesce` expects a constant, not a property expression.

OK, I've tried this:

```
    .Where(() => (taskAlias.StartDateOverride == null
                  ? wiAlias.StartDate
                  : taskAlias.StartDateOverride) <= end)
    .And(() => (taskAlias.EndDateOverride == null
                  ? wiAlias.EndDate
                  : taskAlias.EndDateOverride) >= start)
```

This throws NullReferenceException. Not sure why, but probably either because NHibernate doesn't properly translate that ternary operator (and tries to actually invoke it instead) or because `== null` isn't exactly the right way to check for nulls. Anyway, I didn't even expect it to work.

Finally, this one works:

```
IList<Task> tasks = db.QueryOver<Task>(() => taskAlias)
    .JoinAlias(() => taskAlias.WorkItem, () => wiAlias)
    .Where(Restrictions.LeProperty(
        Projections.SqlFunction("COALESCE", NHibernateUtil.DateTime,
            Projections.Property(() => taskAlias.StartDateOverride),
            Projections.Property(() => wiAlias.StartDate)),
        Projections.Constant(end)))
    .And(Restrictions.GeProperty(
        Projections.SqlFunction("COALESCE", NHibernateUtil.DateTime,
            Projections.Property(() => taskAlias.EndDateOverride),
            Projections.Property(() => wiAlias.EndDate)),
        Projections.Constant(start)))
    .List();
```

But there is no way I can call that clean code. Maybe I can extract certain expressions into separate methods to clean it up a little bit, but it would be much better to use expression syntax rather than these ugly projections. Is there a way to do it? Is there any reason behind NHibernate not supporting property expressions in the `Coalesce` extension?

One obvious alternative is to select everything and then filter results using Linq or whatever. But it could become a performance problem with large number of total rows.

Here is full code in case someone wants to try it:

```
using (ISessionFactory sessionFactory = Fluently.Configure()
    .Database(SQLiteConfiguration.Standard.UsingFile("temp.sqlite").ShowSql())
    .Mappings(m => m.AutoMappings.Add(
        AutoMap.AssemblyOf<Employee>(new ExampleConfig())
            .Conventions.Add(DefaultLazy.Never())
            .Conventions.Add(DefaultCascade.All())))
    .ExposeConfiguration(c => new SchemaExport(c).Create(true, true))
    .BuildSessionFactory())
{
    using (ISession db = sessionFactory.OpenSession())
    {
        Employee empl = new Employee() { Name = "Joe" };
        WorkItem wi = new WorkItem()
        {
            Description = "Important work",
            StartDate = new DateTime(2016, 01, 01),
            EndDate = new DateTime(2017, 01, 01)
        };
        Task task1 = new Task()
        {
            Assignee = empl,
            WorkItem = wi,
            Details = "Do this",
        };
        db.Save(task1);
        Task task2 = new Task()
        {
            Assignee = empl,
            WorkItem = wi,
            Details = "Do that",
            StartDateOverride = new DateTime(2016, 7, 1),
            EndDateOverride = new DateTime(2017, 1, 1),
        };
        db.Save(task2);
        Task taskAlias = null;
        WorkItem wiAlias = null;
        DateTime start = new DateTime(2016, 1, 1);
        DateTime end = new DateTime(2016, 6, 30);
        IList<Task> tasks = db.QueryOver<Task>(() => taskAlias)
            .JoinAlias(() => taskAlias.WorkItem, () => wiAlias)
            // This doesn't compile:
            //.Where(() => taskAlias.StartDateOverride.Coalesce(() => wiAlias.StartDate) <= end)
            //.And(() => taskAlias.EndDateOverride.Coalesce(() => wiAlias.EndDate) >= start)
            // This throws NullReferenceException:
            //.Where(() => (taskAlias.StartDateOverride == null ? wiAlias.StartDate : taskAlias.StartDateOverride) <= end)
            //.And(() => (taskAlias.EndDateOverride == null ? wiAlias.EndDate : taskAlias.EndDateOverride) >= start)
            // This works:
            .Where(Restrictions.LeProperty(
                Projections.SqlFunction("COALESCE", NHibernateUtil.DateTime,
                    Projections.Property(() => taskAlias.StartDateOverride),
                    Projections.Property(() => wiAlias.StartDate)),
                Projections.Constant(end)))
            .And(Restrictions.GeProperty(
                Projections.SqlFunction("COALESCE", NHibernateUtil.DateTime,
                    Projections.Property(() => taskAlias.EndDateOverride),
                    Projections.Property(() => wiAlias.EndDate)),
                Projections.Constant(start)))
            .List();
        foreach (Task t in tasks)
            Console.WriteLine("Found task: {0}", t.Details);
    }
}
```

And the configuration is really simple:

```
class ExampleConfig : DefaultAutomappingConfiguration
{
    public override bool ShouldMap(Type type)
    {
        return type.Namespace == "TryHibernate.Example";
    }
}
```

Comment: Another downvote maniac? I've done my research, I've actually come up with a working solution, I've clearly stated my problem and even provided an example. As if -2 rep actually means something!

Comment: I fully agree with the above comment. All I needed was to create a new console project, install two NuGet packages, copy/paste the provided code and start playing with it. No guesses, no typos, everything compiles/does exactly what is explained in the post or commented in the code. It's really exceptional to find such good `mcve` here for a non trivial issue.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let start with this:

```
// This doesn't compile:
//.Where(() => taskAlias.StartDateOverride.Coalesce(() => wiAlias.StartDate) <= end)
//.And(() => taskAlias.EndDateOverride.Coalesce(() => wiAlias.EndDate) >= start)
```

and modify it to:

```
.Where(() => taskAlias.StartDateOverride.Coalesce(wiAlias.StartDate) <= end)
.And(() => taskAlias.EndDateOverride.Coalesce(wiAlias.EndDate) >= start)
```

now it will compile. But at runtime it generates the same `NullReferenceException`. No good.

It turns out that NHibernate indeed tries to evaluate the `Coalesce` argument. This can easily be seen by looking at `ProjectionExtensions` class implementation. The following method handles the `Coalesce` translation:

```
internal static IProjection ProcessCoalesce(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
{
  IProjection projection = ExpressionProcessor.FindMemberProjection(methodCallExpression.Arguments[0]).AsProjection();
  object obj = ExpressionProcessor.FindValue(methodCallExpression.Arguments[1]);
  return Projections.SqlFunction("coalesce", (IType) NHibernateUtil.Object, projection, Projections.Constant(obj));
}
```

Notice the different handling of the first argument (`FindMemberExpresion`) vs second argument (`FindValue`). Well, `FindValue` simply tries to evaluate the expression.

Now we know what is causing the issue. I have no idea why it is implemented that way, so will concentrate on finding a solution.

Fortunately, the `ExpressionProcessor` class is public and also allows you to register a custom methods via `RegisterCustomMethodCall` / `RegisterCustomProjection` methods. Which leads us to the solution:

- Create a custom extensions methods similar to `Coalesce` (let call them `IfNull` for instance)
- Register a custom processor
- Use them instead of `Coalesce`

Here is the implementation:

```
public static class CustomProjections
{
    static CustomProjections()
    {
        ExpressionProcessor.RegisterCustomProjection(() => IfNull(null, ""), ProcessIfNull);
        ExpressionProcessor.RegisterCustomProjection(() => IfNull(null, 0), ProcessIfNull);
    }

    public static void Register() { }

    public static T IfNull<T>(this T objectProperty, T replaceValueIfIsNull)
    {
        throw new Exception("Not to be used directly - use inside QueryOver expression");
    }

    public static T? IfNull<T>(this T? objectProperty, T replaceValueIfIsNull) where T : struct
    {
        throw new Exception("Not to be used directly - use inside QueryOver expression");
    }

    private static IProjection ProcessIfNull(MethodCallExpression mce)
    {
        var arg0 = ExpressionProcessor.FindMemberProjection(mce.Arguments[0]).AsProjection();
        var arg1 = ExpressionProcessor.FindMemberProjection(mce.Arguments[1]).AsProjection();
        return Projections.SqlFunction("coalesce", NHibernateUtil.Object, arg0, arg1);
    }
}
```

Since these methods are never called, you need to ensure the custom processor is registered by calling `Register` method. It's an empty method just to make sure the static constructor of the class is invoked, where the actual registration happens.

So in your example, include at the beginning:

`CustomProjections.Register();`

then use inside the query:

```
.Where(() => taskAlias.StartDateOverride.IfNull(wiAlias.StartDate) <= end)
.And(() => taskAlias.EndDateOverride.IfNull(wiAlias.EndDate) >= start)
```

and it will work as expected.

P.S. The above implementation works for both constant and expression arguments, so it's really a safe replacement of the `Coalesce`.

Comment: Awesome! And by removing generics, I can actually name it `Coalesce` with no name conflicts, *and* have `NHibernateUtil.Date` instead of `NHibernateUtil.Object` (although it works with either). The trade-off is that I have to create overloads for every type I need, but at the time it's only one.

Comment: Interesting idea, I didn't think in that direction. A little bit annoying if you need to do it for many types, but works! Actually I have another solution, but it's a bit hacky. Instead of custom extension methods, just replace the  handler for the two `Coalesce` methods (they are registered the same way). But in order to remove the previous handlers we need to access their private dictionary via reflection. And of course you can request/suggest NHibernate fix (will take time), apply the fix in the source code and use custom NHibernate build (maintenance, updates) etc. A lot of choices :-)